# How to mount .raw disk image with no partition table

Tags: partitioning, mount, fdisk, disk-image

I need help.
I try to mount disk image from a file in raw format
and I cant see any partitions on it, so I don`t know how to mount these file.

```
fdisk -l file.raw 
Disk file.raw: 2 GiB, 2147482624 bytes, 4194302 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

---

```
gdisk -l file.raw 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Warning: File size is not a multiple of 512 bytes! Misbehavior is likely!
Warning: File size is not a multiple of 512 bytes! Misbehavior is likely!
Warning: File size is not a multiple of 512 bytes! Misbehavior is likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk file.raw: 4194302 sectors, 2.0 GiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): XXXXXXX
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 4194268
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4194235 sectors (2.0 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

Comment: Do you know which filesystem type the image contains?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [kpartx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/kpartx.8.html): `sudo apt-get install kpartx` and then create loop devices with `sudo kpartx -a -v file.raw` .

If above method fails, make a copy of `file.raw` and run [testdisk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/testdisk.8.html) for this file to restore partition table by: `sudo apt-get install testdisk` and `testdisk file.raw`.

If nothing helped - run R-Studio against this file to get the data and partition table back.